# meaning of "for if" in this sentence

Tags: conditionals, clauses

I can eat anything in this buffet including the lamb chops for dinner only, for if I pay the full price.

Does the "if I pay the full price" clause apply to everything before it?

Comment: That sentence is not grammatical English.

Comment: The "for if" construction does exist in English (although it's a bit dated) but it does _not_ mean (as I think you are trying to make it mean here) "if I pay the full price for it" or even "if I pay the full price". "For if" is only used to mean "because if" as in the sentence "I cannot have lamb chops for dinner_for if_ I have a glass of wine I will not have enough money to pay the full price.

Comment: I can't help but feel the sentence should have continued after "full price". He was just getting up to a conclusion.